# Delphi - thread stopped by user or self-terminate after a period of time

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe6

Based on several questions here on SO, I've implemented a thread which can be killed by user before finishing it's job, or if I'm setting it to self-terminate after a period of time.

Thread implementation:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses SyncObjs
     ,classes
     ,System.SysUtils
     ,windows;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FTerminateEvent: TEvent;
    FTimerStart: Cardinal;
    FTimerLimit: Cardinal;
    FTimeout: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure TerminatedSet; override;
  public
    constructor Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean; Timeout: Cardinal); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyThread.Create(ACreateSuspended: Boolean; TimeOut: Cardinal);
begin
  inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);
  FTerminateEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, True, False, '');
  FTimerStart:=GetTickCount;
  FTimerLimit:=Timeout;
  FTimeout:=True;
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar('destroy '+inttostr(Handle)));
  inherited;
  FTerminateEvent.Free;
end;

procedure TMyThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  FTerminateEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  FTimerNow:Cardinal;
begin
  FTimerNow:=GetTickCount;

  while not(Terminated) and ((FTimerNow-FTimerStart)<FTimerLimit) do
  begin
   OutputDebugString(PChar('execute '+inttostr(Handle)));

   FTerminateEvent.WaitFor(100);

   FTimerNow:=GetTickCount;
  end;
  if (FTimerNow-FTimerStart) > FTimerLimit then
   begin
    self.Free;
   end;
end;

end.
```

and how the threads are created in the main unit of the app

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs
  ,unit2, Vcl.StdCtrls
  ;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
   t1,t2: TMyThread;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//
  if t1 = nil then
   t1 := TMyThread.Create(false,10000)
  else
 if t2 = nil then
   t2 := TMyThread.Create(False,10000);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//
  if t1 <> nil then
   begin
    t1.Free;
    t1 := nil;
   end
  else
   if t2 <> nil then
    begin
     t2.Free;
     t2 := nil;
    end;
end;

end.
```

What I want is a worker thread that stops either when I'm killing it, either after a period of time. Problem appears when the thread needs to self-terminate, because there I get memory leaks and my event does not get freed.

LE: setting up the `FreeOnTerminate` to `True` results in multiple access violations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here are the dangling references to your threads stored in `t1` and `t2`.

So you must take care of this references. The best option is to use the `TThread.OnTerminate` event to get informed whenever a thread has come to an end. Combined with `TThread.FreeOnTerminate` set to `true` should solve your problems.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//
  if t1 = nil then
  begin
   t1 := TMyThread.Create(false,10000);
   t1.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminate;
   t1.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  end
  else if t2 = nil then
  begin
   t2 := TMyThread.Create(False,10000);
   t2.OnTermiante := ThreadTerminate; 
   t2.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//
  if t1 <> nil then
    t1.Terminate
  else if t2 <> nil then
    t2.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminate( Sender : TObject );
begin
  if Sender = t1 then
    t1 := nil
  else if Sender = t2 then
    t2 := nil;
end;
```

**UPDATE**

You should never free the instance itself with `Self.Free`. This will lead you to dangling references by design.

Comment: It is a bad idea to call Terminate on a thread instance that is `FreeOnTerminate`. It could be freed already by a timeout. Also managing the nil setting is not needed at all. Just create the threads from a local variable or without any variable.

Comment: Use a flag instead to tell when the thread has finished its job in the `OnTerminate` event.

Comment: @LURD The event [`TThread.OnTerminate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate) is a synchronized call inside the MainThread context. If you enter the Method `TForm1.Button2Click` you will have a valid reference in `t1`/`t2` or a `nil` reference. So this approach is safe

Comment: Yes this way is safe, but still this approach is prone to mistakes sooner or later.

Answer (score 4):

Setting `FreeOnTerminate` to true, means you should **never** try to access an instance of `TMyThread`. You can never predict if the instance is valid once you try to access it.

It is also an error to call `Self.Free` within the `Execute` method. Just let the `Execute` method finish its job and the rest is taken care of.

The safe way to let the thread terminate after a certain time or by an event, is to pass an external event handler to your thread and setting the `FreeOnTerminate` to true.

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting `TThread.FreeOnTerminate` property to true. This will destroy the Thread object once execution is finished.

Keep in mind that you cannot access any public property after thread execution ends. This approach works only if you don't need to read something from thread once terminated.

Comment: I've tried that and due to the anatomy of the thread it results in multiple access violations.